# Amazon EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, reinstall

I have an EC2 instance what I can not repair. I was trying to make an upgrade but everything fails.
Would be possible to reinstall an amazon ec2 instance running on Ubuntu server?

Comment: Just create a new instance and terminate the old one.

Comment: I already made that! But would be good to know if is possible to backup my new micro instance

Comment: Sure, you can create an AMI of the instance periodically, which lets you launch clones of it. You should also probably back up anything important just like you'd back up a non-EC2 instance.

Comment: okay thanks a lot.I look forward how to make AMI from existing instances.

Answer (score 2):

> Would be possible to reinstall an amazon ec2 instance running on
>   Ubuntu server?

You could terminiate your existing instance and create a brand new one.

> But would be good to know if is possible to backup my new micro
>   instance

You can create a snapshot of any instance type by right clicking it and selecting "Create Image (EBS AMI)".

Alternatively you can use the command line tools, ie "ec2-create-snapshot"

After creating a snapshot, or AMI (Amazon Machine Image) you can launch new instances based off this image (this would essentially be restoring the backup).

This might help as it takes you through the steps in detail: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-create-a-new-ami-from-a-snapshot-and-launch-a-new-vm/5349

Comment: If the original sever won't boot, cloning may not help. It may be best to launch a new server from the base OS AMI, then attach the old drive and copy the data off.